# Ошибка в Celery: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tasks'"

Tags: python, celery

При запуске батника для включения Celery:

```
python.exe -m celery -A .tasks worker.celery -P eventlet -f celery.logs -l info
```

Вываливается ошибка:

```
>Traceback (most recent call last):<br>
File "C:\Users\Chernov.a\Desktop\Projects\Roscosmos\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
        "__main__", mod_spec)
<br>File "C:\Users\Chernov.a\Desktop\Projects\Roscosmos\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
<br>File "C:\Users\Chernov.a\Desktop\Projects\Roscosmos\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\celery\__main__.py", line 18, in <module>
main()
<br>File "C:\Users\Chernov.a\Desktop\Projects\Roscosmos\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\celery\__main__.py", line 14, in main
        _main()
<br>File "C:\Users\Chernov.a\Desktop\Projects\Roscosmos\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 326, in main
        cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
<br>File "C:\Users\Chernov.a\Desktop\Projects\Roscosmos\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 488, in execute_from_commandline<br>
        super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
<br>File "C:\Users\Chernov.a\Desktop\Projects\Roscosmos\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", line 279, in execute_from_commandline
<br>argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
<br>File "C:\Users\Chernov.a\Desktop\Projects\Roscosmos\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", line 481, in setup_app_from_commandline
<br>self.app = self.find_app(app)
<br>File "C:\Users\Chernov.a\Desktop\Projects\Roscosmos\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", line 503, in find_app
<br>return find_app(app, symbol_by_name=self.symbol_by_name)
<br>File "C:\Users\Chernov.a\Desktop\Projects\Roscosmos\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\celery\app\utils.py", line 355, in find_app
<br>sym = symbol_by_name(app, imp=imp)
<br>File "C:\Users\Chernov.a\Desktop\Projects\Roscosmos\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", line 506, in symbol_by_name
<br>return imports.symbol_by_name(name, imp=imp)
<br>File "C:\Users\Chernov.a\Desktop\Projects\Roscosmos\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kombu\utils\imports.py", line 56, in symbol_by_name
<br>module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
<br>File "C:\Users\Chernov.a\Desktop\Projects\Roscosmos\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\celery\utils\imports.py", line 101, in import_from_cwd
<br>return imp(module, package=package)
<br>File "C:\Users\Chernov.a\Desktop\Projects\Roscosmos\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
<br>return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
<br>File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
<br>File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
<br>File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
<br>ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tasks'
```

Пробовал в syspath  добавить данный путь, сменить окружение, закинуть в Виртуальное окружение и другие советы - ничего не помогло.

Сам код
*tasks.py*

```
#Импорт библиотеки для HTTP- запросов
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
#Импорт бибилиотеки менеджера очередей
from celery import Celery

#Инициализация экземпляра менеджера очередей
celery_app = Celery('nsi', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

#Создание фоновой задачи
@celery_app.task(
    name='sendToNsi',
    default_retry_delay = 4 *(60 * 60),
    max_retries =  1000,
    autoretry_for=(Exception,))

def sendToNsi(NSI_url,answer):
#Отправка сообщения в НСИ
    s=requests.Session()
    post_request = s.post(NSI_url, data=answer,auth=HTTPBasicAuth('gk', 'gkpass'))
    post_request.raise_for_status()
```

*views.py*

```
# Импорт модулей
import pyodbc as pyodbc
from flask import request, Response
from webNSI import app
import logging
from webNSI.config import *
from webNSI.model.Answers import *
from webNSI.model.DBOperation import *
from webNSI.model.MQ.tasks import *
from webNSI.model.XmlHandler import *

#Настройки логирования
logging.basicConfig(filename='log.log',
                    format = u'%(filename)s[LINE:%(lineno)d]# %(levelname)-8s [%(asctime)s]  %(message)s',
                    level = logging.DEBUG) # Настройки Логирования




#Обработка xml
def process_xml(xml):

    clean_xml = re.compile('xsi:').sub('',xml)  # Очистка xml  от xsi:
    soup = Soup(clean_xml,'xml')                # Перевод во внутренний формат
    result_list = []                            # Список с результатами парсинга xml
    item_soup = soup.find_all("Item")           # Поиск всех элементов с тэгом "Item"
    for elem in item_soup:
        attribute = {                           #Словарь для каждого контрагента с необходимыми данными
        'id': '',
        'Name': '',
        'FullName': '',
        'INN': '',
        'OKPO': '',
        'OKVED': '',
        "OrgType": '',
        "OKONH": '',
        "YurAddress": '',
        'Adress': '',
        'KPP':'',
        'GID':'',
        'ID': ''
    }
        attribute["GID"] = elem.find("GID").text
        attribute["ID"] = elem.find("id").text

        property_soup = elem.find_all("Property")
        lids = elem.find_all("LID")


        for value in property_soup:
            try:
                if value.find("PropertyID").text == "Наименование":

                    attribute["Name"]=value.find("valueString").text
                if value.find("PropertyID").text == "НаименованиеПолное":
                    attribute["FullName"] = value.find("valueString").text
                if value.find("PropertyID").text == "000000009":
                    attribute["INN"] = value.find("Value").text
                if value.find("PropertyID").text == '000000010':
                    attribute["KPP"] = value.find("Value").text
                if value.find("PropertyID").text == '000000032':
                    attribute["OKPO"] = value.find("Value").text
                if value.find("PropertyID").text == "000000001":
                    attribute["YurAddress"] = value.find("Value").text
                if value.find("PropertyID").text == '000000035':
                    if value.find("name").text == "ЮЛ":
                        attribute["OrgType"] = "1"
                    else:
                        attribute["OrgType"] = '0'
            except Exception as e:
                return "Exception"
            for lid in lids:
                if len(lid.text) == 36:
                    attribute['id'] = lid.text


        result_list.append(attribute)
    return result_list


#Сбор метаданных xml
def meta_dat(xml):
    clean_xml = re.compile('xsi:').sub('', xml)
    soup = Soup(clean_xml, 'xml')
    try:
        message_soup = soup.find("MessageID")
        return message_soup.text
    except Exception as e:
        return answer_for_clent_parsing_error(describtion="ParseError: Cannot read metadate of message")




#Общий запуск сервиса
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return ("Service is run")


#Rest метод для отправки контрагента
@app.route('/contragent', methods=['POST'])
def accept_xml():
    body_response = ''

    xml=request.data.decode("utf-8")

    try:
        parses_list = process_xml(xml)
        if parses_list == "Exception":
            raise Exception
    except Exception as e:
        describtion = "Parsing Error: Invalid format of Message"
        body_response += answer_for_clent_parsing_error(describtion)
        sendToNsi.delay(NSI_url, answer=answer_to_client(meta_dat(xml), body_response ))
        logging.error(" Parsing Error : {}".format(e))
        return answer_to_client(meta_dat(xml), body_response )

    for elem in parses_list:

        id = elem["id"]
        Name = elem ['Name']
        FullName = elem['FullName']
        INN = elem['INN']
        OKPO = elem['OKPO']
        OKVED = elem['OKVED']
        OrgType = elem["OrgType"]
        OKONH = elem["OKONH"]
        YurAddress = elem["YurAddress"]
        Adress = elem ['Adress']
        KPP = elem["KPP"]
        GID = elem["GID"]
        ID=elem["ID"]


        try:
            if check_ca(id) == 1:
                body_response += changing_in_table(id,KPP,OKPO,OKONH,Name,FullName,ID,GID)
                logging.info(" Contractor   Name:{}  successfully changed").format(Name)
            elif check_ca(id) == None:
                body_response += add_in_table(id,Name,OrgType,INN,KPP,OKPO,OKONH,FullName,ID,GID,SDID,InstanceID)

        except pyodbc.InterfaceError as e:

            describtion = " Could not connect to database "
            body_response += answer_for_clent_error(GID,ID,id,describtion)

            sendToNsi(NSI_url, answer=answer_to_client(meta_dat(xml), body_response + " "))
            logging.error("Database connection is failed: {}".format(e))
            return "" 
        except pyodbc.OperationalError as e:

            describtion = "Could not connect to database"
            #logging.ERROR("Не удалось подключиться к базе данных: " + str(e))
            body_response += answer_for_clent_error(GID, ID, id, describtion)
            sendToNsi.delay(NSI_url, answer=answer_to_client(meta_dat(xml), body_response + " "))
            logging.error("Database connection is failed: {}".format(e))
            return "" 
        except pyodbc.ProgrammingError as e:
            logging.error("Database connection is failed: {}".format(e))
            describtion = "Could not connect to database"
            sendToNsi.delay(NSI_url, answer=answer_to_client(meta_dat(xml), body_response + " "))
            return "" 
    sendToNsi.delay(NSI_url, answer=answer_to_client(meta_dat(xml), body_response))
    #Возврат сообщения о результатах отправки контрагента
    return  answer_to_client(meta_dat(xml), body_response )
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: название tasks.py , опечатался

Comment: Попробуйте убрать точку перед tasks и повторно запустить.

Comment: Не помогло, пробовал.